# reuse bond created during BT classic pairing for connecting through BLE

Tags: android, ios, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I pair 2 Nexus phones through BT classic.
Then, Nexus #1 advertises a service through BLE, and Nexus #2 scans, recognizes the MAC from bonded devices and can subscribe to a characteristic.

Now, doing the same thing with Nexus #2 and an iPhone, the MAC exposed by the iPhone during the BT pairing is different than the one exposed during the BLE advertising, and a 2nd pairing is required in order to connect and subscribe to a characteristic. That's for security purpose I assume.

Question: is there any way to prevent 2 pair events? Since the devices are known from each other after the BT pairing, is there a way to reuse that bond to connect them through BLE?